# Problemas en la migracion con laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Estoy creando unas migraciones y estoy agrupando lo de paises, regiones, provincias y ciudades en el mismo archivo. Lo estoy haciendo de la forma como esta en el código, el problema es que me estra marcando el error de mas abajo.

cosas que he hecho :

- Poner el campo de llave foránea como entero
- Ponerle y quitarle , la longitud del campo como segundo argumento
- Cambiar el campo que sera la foránea como bigInteger - integer - unsigned
- Les he puesto unsigned a los campos llave
- he puesto  deshabilitar / habilitar de foráneas por si las
  moscas y tampoco

No se me ocurre mas nada

Me dice que debe haber solo una columna autoincrementable pero la verdad es que tengo solo una, la de las llaves primarias nada mas.

**Tengo el diagrama hecho en workbench y al correrlo con el forward enginner lo hace sin problemas.**

También he de decir que este es el primer archivo de migraciones no deben correr migraciones delante de estos , al contrario deben ser primeros.

Muchas gracias.

```
public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->char('iso3466a1', 2);
            $table->char('iso3466a2', 3);
            $table->string('country');

            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('regions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('country_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('region');
            $table->integer('capital', 11);

            $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');

            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('countries');
        Schema::dropIfExists('regions');
    }
```

El error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect
>   table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be
>   defined as a key (SQL: create table `regions` (`id` bigint unsigned
>   not null auto_increment primary key, `country_id` bigint unsigned not
>   null, `slug` varchar(191) not null, `region` varchar(191) not null,
>   `capital` int not null auto_increment primary key, `created_at`
>   timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set
>   utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Comment: La tabla `regions` tiene dos primary keys en la definición que describe el error y eso no es válido. Algo falta en la definición del campo capital para que no intente hacerlo PK

Comment: @Alfabravo te refieres a este campo `country_id`?

Comment: Hola chicos. @Alfabravo  Supongo que mencionas esto porque esta declarada como bigInteger. Este campo lo he declarado tambien con integer+ unsigned y tampoco. Asi mismo como segundo param le he puesto un valor y tampoco.

Comment: En tu error sale `id bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key` y luego sale `capital int not null auto_increment primary key`. Hay dos PK

Comment: Si efectivamente, la verdad soy nuevo con laravel y aunque he tirado algunas lineas de código con el hay muchas cosas que me cuesta entender. Lo primero es como se define ese campo como primary ?? Lo he probado con integer, colocando unsigned, tambien valor de longitud, sin el valor y me sale el mismo error y es laravel el que lo hace porque el lanzar el codigo sql como tal desde el workbench no hace eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya tengo la respuesta:

He probando la migracion de tu ejemplo y el problema es el siguiente:

1) La declaracion para el campo `$table->integer('capital', 11);` es errado no se considera correcta, no permite parametros en el Schemabuilder por lo que reporta el error que lo identifica como si tuvieras declarando dos llaves. La correcta sintaxis es:

```
$table->integer('capital');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2) Si se puede crear dos tablas simultaneamente dentro de una migracion, **lo acabo de probar y SI FUNCIONA!**,  Lo que NO es recomentable porque pierdes todo sentido porque no podras hacer rollback individual, crear migraciones incrementales con su numero de cola batch. (En ese aspecto **Aprendiz** tiene razon al recomendarte hacer migraciones separadas)

Entonces el codigo de tu migracion deberia ser el siguiente:

Si aun desea crear dos tabla en una migracion:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->char('iso3466a1', 2);
            $table->char('iso3466a2', 3);
            $table->string('country');

            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('regions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('country_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('region');
            $table->integer('capital');

            $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');

            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('countries');
        Schema::dropIfExists('regions');
    }
```

**LO RECOMENDABLE, (hacer migraciones individuales)**

**Para la tabla region:**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('region', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('country_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('region');
            $table->integer('capital'); // no usar falla $table->integer('capital', 11);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');

        });

        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('region');
    }
```

**para la tabla paises:**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->char('iso3466a1', 2);
            $table->char('iso3466a2', 3);
            $table->string('country');

            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('countries');
    }
```

Adjunto a la respuesta una **tabla de los campos tipo numericos** que puedes usar:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

Es un campo de autoincremento del tipo UNSIGNED BIGINT con llave primara.

```
$table->bigInteger('votes');
```

BIGINT campo o equivalente.

```
$table->decimal('amount', 8, 2);
```

DECIMAL campo o equivalente precisión (con dígitos enteros y decimales).

```
$table->double('amount', 8, 2);
```

DOUBLE campo o equivalente precisión (con dígitos enteros y decimales).

```
$table->float('amount', 8, 2);
```

FLOAT campo o equivalente precisión (con dígitos enteros y decimales).

```
$table->increments('id');
```

Es un campo de autoincremento del tipo UNSIGNED INTEGER con llave primara.

```
$table->integer('votes');
```

INTEGER campo o equivalente.

```
$table->mediumIncrements('id');
```

Es un campo de autoincremento del tipo UNSIGNED MEDIUMINT con llave primara

```
$table->mediumInteger('votes');
```

MEDIUMINT campo o equivalente..

```
$table->smallIncrements('id');
```

Es un campo de autoincremento del tipo UNSIGNED SMALLINT con llave primara

```
$table->smallInteger('votes');
```

SMALLINT campo o equivalente

```
$table->tinyIncrements('id');
```

Es un campo de autoincremento del tipo UNSIGNED TINYINT con llave primara.

```
$table->tinyInteger('votes');
```

TINYINT campo o equivalente

Comment: buena idea, voy  ampliar la respuesta

Comment: Alexander muchas gracias pir tu respuesta, la verdad ayer estuve haciendo pruebas y me ha funcionado algo y he notado lo siguiente. Los tiros van mas o menos por lo que mencionas tu. Solo que hay algunas cosas que hay me han aparecido a mi.

Comment: Gracias Alexander por tu respuesta. He encontrado otra cosa la definicion como la tengo en el ejemplo en principio me ha  funcionado cambiando un detalle, el **bigIncrements** que viene por defecto a solo **increments**. No se si esto se deba a la version mysql o tenga que ver es solo con laravel, en ese punto tendre que invetigar un poco mas , pero me ha funcionado este cambio de bigIncrements a increments. Gracias. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Yo separaría la creación de las tablas en 2 archivos de migraciones distintos, es decir:

- migración `countries`
- migración `regions`

**Edición**

> Después de revisar en un ejemplo y comprobar lo acotado en un comentario, te recomiendo que para mantener la declaración de la longitud de tu columna `capital` como un entero de *11* entonces hagas esto:

```
$table->integer('capital')->length(11);
```

Con lo anterior se creará la tabla evitando el error mencionado y de hecho si le haces un `DESCRIBE` a la tabla mencionada verás lo siguiente:

```
MariaDB [seis]> describe regions;
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| country_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| slug       | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| region     | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| capital    | int(11)             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.143 sec)
```

Entonces el método `up()` de tu migración `countries` solo debería tener lo siguiente:

```
public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->char('iso3466a1', 2);
            $table->char('iso3466a2', 3);
            $table->string('country');

            $table->timestamps();
        });


    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('countries');
    }
```

Ahora en tu migración de `regions` el método `up()` debe tener esto:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('regions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('country_id');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('region');
            $table->integer('capital')->length(11);

            $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');

            $table->timestamps();
        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('regions');
    }
```

Una vez hecho lo anterior ejecuta de nuevo las migraciones con

```
php artisan migrante:fresh
```

- Aqui [puedes leer mas sobre las migraciones](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations)
- Considera tener la creación de tablas, una por cada archivo de migración que estés creando

Comment: Hola Aprendiz.Gracias por tu respuesta, lo he hecho de la forma como lo dices pero tampoco funciona, he reescrito el código varias veces con modificaciones y ninguna ha funcionado. Siempre me dice no puede crear la llave foránea, crea las tablas pero al llegar al punto del foreign no lo hace.

Comment: Lo siento habia escrito mal un par de cosas, que hasta que leí de nuevo mis migraciones me di cuenta que aunque las noté no las corregí

Comment: Gracias Aprendiz por tu respuesta. He encontrado otra cosa la definicion como la tengo en el ejemplo en principio me ha funcionado cambiando un detalle, el bigIncrements que viene por defecto a solo increments. No se si esto se deba a la version mysql o tenga que ver es solo con laravel, en ese punto tendre que invetigar un poco mas , pero me ha funcionado este cambio de bigIncrements a increments. Gracias. Saludos